# Radiance increase via two sources

Tags: visible-light

Can two sources of white light shined at the same general location increase the resulting rasiance?

Comment: [Radiance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance) is a property of *emitting objects*, so I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: Suppose I use a light detector to inspect said location. Would it detect a greater intensity when the two sources shine there, rather then one source?

Comment: Then that the quantity that you are asking about is either *irradiance* (W/m${}^2$) or *radiant flux*  (W).  But I can't be sure what you have in mind.  I suggest editing your question to be more clear.  Otherwise you might get all kinds of responses that don't answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining Multiple Light Sources](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/combining-multiple-light-sources)

Comment: Its not 'radiance' but "illuminance" which is the total luminous flux over a given area (measured in "lumens per $m^2$" which is called "lux", $lx$).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would get more 'photons per second', which is *photon flux* (not intensity).

Strictly speaking, the light intensity is the power of electromagnetic radiation incident per unit area on a surface, known as *irradiance*. This is a function of the energy of the photon $E_P$, so would vary with wavelength $\lambda$, where:

$$E_P=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

So If one light source is emitting red light and the other blue light, to get the same intensity (irradiance), the blue light requires less photon flux (fewer photons per second) than red light, since the energy content if each photon is greater (blue light has shorter wavelength than red).

'White' light is in fact a 'mixture' of colours across the spectrum of visible electromagnetic radiation. As such, lighting manufacturers typically quote a given lamp's total output in terms of a 'wavelength-weighted energy' (measured in 'lumens' $lm$).

[image]

Different lamp designs throw light out in different directions, so the manufacturers also typically provide a polar graph with each lamp, showing the luminous intensity (candela $cd$) as a function of angle (measured from the vertical). For example, in the polar diagram, the lamp would have a luminous intensity of 3000 cd at 30° from the vertical).

[image]

A lighting engineer would typically specify the level of 'illuminance' (measured in 'lux' $lx$) required for an area (such as a work area). The 'brightness' of the light is the total amount of visible light illuminating a point on a surface from all directions above the surface, taking into account the luminous intensity, distance and direction of light sources.

There are various methods for calculating the illuminance for a given lighting configuration. A simple manual calculation may just involve determination of the total light flux (in lumens) incident on the working plane, assuming that it is evenly distributed over the area, dividing it by the area $lx=lm/m^2$.

NOTE: To be more accurate, a 'real-world' calculation would take into account room dimensions, reflectance values, light loss and other factors. Typically, computer programs are employed to make these calculations on a point-by-point basis, also taking into account 'inverse square' law and cosine saw where applicable.

Comment: But since photons carry energy, doesn't it follow that getting more photons per sencond per unit area means you're getting more energy into the detector?

(assuming the detection area and the integration time remain the same in both cases).

Comment: But if the two photons are of different wavelength, they would each carry different energy, so 'irradiance' (in $W/m^2)$ would be different.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your last comment...

Also, please refer to this question (I just found right now, truely:)

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/combining-multiple-light-sources?rq=1

Comment: See edits (last paragraph) in my answer.

Comment: But notice that I was asking about two white light sources (and let us assume that they are virtually indentical).

Comment: So for 'white light', which consists of electromagnetic radiation across the visible light spectrum, we must use a 'weighted-sum' of frequencies, as defined in various 'luminosity' standards in photometry. These basically aim to specify a 'predictable' response for the human eye. See further edits (last 2 paragraphs) in my answer.

Comment: So returning to my question - will my detector detect a greater intensity (also called radiance, as far as I know) when the two white light sources are focused to our reigon of interest?

If no, please explain, because it would seem to me like it sould.

Comment: Although 'radiance' is a general term for 'intensity of electromagnetic radiation' (measured in $W/m^2$), when talking about "visible light", the terms 'irradiance' (mesured in $W/m^2$) or 'illuminance'(measured in "lumens per $m^2$" commonly called "lux") are used. To answer your question in brief, yes two sources of light illuminating the same area will increase the 'illuminance'.

Comment: This post does not address OP's question at all.

Comment: @pentane Oh really?  Why not? Why do you suppose OP has accepted the answer?

Comment: Not really sure. Probably OP found the correct answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/combining-multiple-light-sources?rq=1

Comment: @pentane Well OP has accepted this answer, so perhaps you should remove your downvote which was made after the fact

Comment: @pentane In any case... not exactly the same question. OP has asked about 'radiance' which I've explained in terms of 'irradiance' and 'illuminance'.